# Create Application Insights using Azure Fluent API

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, fluent

Is there a way to specifically create an Application Insights using Azure Fluent API? 
I see there is a Monitor code sample, but this is not specific to Application Insights.

**EDIT:**
After trying the [Azure SDK API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/?view=azure-dotnet) from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51256101/create-application-insights-using-azure-fluent-api#answer-51259256), I got an error not identified in their [documentation](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Using-the-API/Errors).

[image]

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread?

Comment: @TomSun I had problems using the API

Answer (score 1):

Currently Fluent API does not support for **[Application Insights](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/issues/354)**.

> It appears the .NET Fluent Azure libraries do not support Application
>   Insight provisioning while the Java SDK does

Same with C# too.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Azure SDK API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/?view=azure-dotnet), there is no Application Insight management API currently.

But we could create the Application Insights with following API. For more information, please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/components/createorupdate).

You could test it directly with [**try it**].

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Insights/components/{resourceName}?api-version=2015-05-01
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an old topic, but apparently Application Insights still isn't part of the [Azure Management API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.appservice.fluent?view=azure-dotnet) yet. I created a class for this, which works a bit like the Fluent API would.

```
public class AppInsights
{
    public IAzureRestClient azureRestClient { get; private set; }

    public AppInsights(IAzureRestClient client)
    {
        this.azureRestClient = client;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Tags { get; private set; }
    public AppInsights WithTags(Dictionary<string, string> tags)
    {
        this.Tags = tags;
        return this;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public AppInsights WithName(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public string SubscriptionId { get; private set; }
    public AppInsights WithSubscriptionId(string id)
    {
        this.SubscriptionId = id;
        return this;
    }

    public IResourceGroup ResourceGroup { get; private set; }
    public AppInsights WithResourceGroup(IResourceGroup group)
    {
        this.ResourceGroup = group;
        return this;
    }

    public string AssociatedApp { get; private set; }
    public AppInsights WithAssociatedApp(string appName)
    {
        this.AssociatedApp = appName;
        return this;
    }

    public AppInsightsComponent Create()
    {
        // initialize tags
        var tags = new Dictionary<string, string>(Tags);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AssociatedApp))
        {
            // Add a tag to associate the App Insights instance with the app service
            // ARM syntax for this: "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('webSiteName'))]": "Resource",
            tags.Add($"hidden-link:{ResourceGroup.Id}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{Name}-portal", "Resource");
        }

        // Create the resource

        var url = $"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{SubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroup.Name}/providers/Microsoft.Insights/components/{Name}?api-version=2015-05-01";

        dynamic reqBody = new JObject();
        reqBody.Location = ResourceGroup.RegionName;
        reqBody.Kind = "web";
        reqBody.tags = JObject.FromObject(tags);
        dynamic properties = new JObject();
        properties.ApplicationType = "web";
        properties.FlowType = "Bluefield";
        properties.RequestSource = "rest";
        reqBody.Properties = properties;

        var response = azureRestClient.Put(url, reqBody);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new HttpRequestException($"management.azure.com returned {response.StatusCode.ToString()}");
        }

        var responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppInsightsComponent>(responseBody);

    }
```

There's more context on [this github page](https://github.com/auzick/FunctionSandbox/blob/master/FunctionSandbox.Provision/AppInsights.cs).